# Git merge upstream and have remote branch on local machine

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I am using git command line.

I have forked repository and have my own copy. i make changes in my repository and then merge using following commands

Step 1. git fetch upstream (fetch remote)

it showed my following log

```
 * [new branch]      1.1        -> upstream/1.1
   6692bb8..cd698e9  master     -> upstream/master
 * [new tag]         1.1.0      -> 1.1.0
```

Step 2. git merge upstream/master (Merge with master)

After i did Step 2. I wants to have branch upstream/1.1 into my local repo, when i forked it was only two branches 'master' and 1.0 thats what i was able to have these both when i cloned it.

If i run 'git brach' on my local machine it shows me i have 'master' and 1.0 how can i have 1.1 into my local repo with re-forking my main repo again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to make `upstream/1.1` branch available in the local repo?

Then, since you already did `git fetch`, a simple `git checkout 1.1` should do that.

Comment: yes you are correct how to have upstream/1.1 in local repo. yes i did git checkout 1.1 and i can see this branch in my local repo. but when i wants to push it complains b/c there is no branch 1.1 in my fork repo. any help ?

Comment: yes that worked for me. but i found my local 1.1 is connected to upstream/1.1 and if i push any changes into local 1.1 it is getting push to upstream/1.1 instead i want changes to go into my forked repo/1.1

Comment: By doing `git push -u origin 1.1` you are specifying that the remote branch for your local 1.1 one to be the forked 1.1 branch.

Comment: Using `git remote show origin` should show you what is linked to the forked repo. `git remote show upstream` should show what is linked to the upstream remote location.

Comment: git push -u origin 1.1 worked for me before i forgot to add "-u" param result to when i was pushing some thing into 1.1 it was going to upstream/1.1 instead of forked/1.1